# What does the userid in received by header indicate?

Tags: postfix

I have a Received header from an e-mail as follows:

```
Received: by aaa.bbb.ccc (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id A70248414D5; Sun, 26 Apr 2020 16:49:01 +0200 (CEST)
```

What does the userid part stand for? 
Is it the UID of the receiving postfix process?
Is it the UID of the sender? How is it determined?

Note I have seen [posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/333176/remove-userid-from-recieved-header) indicating that this is generated when using PHP's `mail()` function.
I just can't seem to find details on how the uid is determined.

Comment: Userid 0 means root.

Comment: Thank you @davidgo. I was aware of that. That is why it caught my attention in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't indicate the mail was sent using PHP [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, as it's just one example of applications sending mail **through Sendmail**. It could be anything that utilizes **Postfix's *local submissions***. From Postfix Architecture Overview: [How Postfix receives mail](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html#receiving):

> Local submissions are received with the Postfix [sendmail(1)](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html)
>   compatibility command, and are queued in the [maildrop queue](http://www.postfix.org/QSHAPE_README.html#maildrop_queue) by the
>   privileged [postdrop(1)](http://www.postfix.org/postdrop.1.html) command. This arrangement even works while the
>   Postfix mail system is not running. The local [pickup(8)](http://www.postfix.org/pickup.8.html) server picks
>   up local submissions, enforces some sanity checks to protect Postfix,
>   and gives the sender, recipients and message content to the [cleanup(8)](http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html)
>   server.

The `pickup` is aware of the user that used the `postdrop`.

```
postfix/pickup[4771]: A70248414D5: uid=0 from=<root>
```

The `cleanup` adds a unique message ID and a received header based on this information.

```
postfix/cleanup[4776]: cleanup_header_callback: 
    'Received: by example.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
       ??id A70248414D5; Sun, 26 Apr 2020 16:49:01 +0200 (CEST)'
postfix/cleanup[4776]: A70248414D5: message-id=<20200426144901.A70248414D5@example.com>
```

The `from` literally means the user the message is from.

**The `userid 0` indicates it's from the `root`.**

Comment: Thank you Esa. That was exactly the details I was looking for. I mentioned the PHP part, because I know for a fact that this e-mail was triggered by a web application (it was an order-confirmation). So seeing uid 0 (i.e. root) made me wonder if that could be used as an indicator that the application (or rather the process executing the PHP interpreter) was running as root.

Comment: I thought this would be the correct level of detail for your needs. How the `pickup` gets this knowledge is another story.